# Excel - compare and move data between sheets

Tags: excel

I get error 9 subscript out of range with this. printing the value if i and ii both show 3 which is what row the data should start on. best i can figure is its not able to read the data from prev report, which is identical to upt report

```
  For i = 3 To lastRowReport
   For ii = 3 To lastRowPrev
      If Worksheets("UPT Report").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("UPT Prev").Cells(ii, 1) 
       Then 
         Worksheets("UPT Prev").Range(Cells(ii, 1), Cells(ii, 22)).Value = 
         Worksheets("UPT Report").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 22)).Value
       Else
        Worksheets("UPT Report").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 22)).Copy
        Worksheets("UPT Prev").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PastSpecial xlPasteValues
      End If
   Next ii
Next i
```

after adjusting the code too

```
 lastblankrow = lastRowPrev + 1
 For i = 3 To lastRowReport
   For ii = 3 To lastRowPrev
      If Worksheets("UPT Report").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("UPT Prev").Cells(ii, 1).Value Then
     Worksheets("UPT Prev").Range(Worksheets("UPT Prev").Cells(ii, 1), Worksheets("UPT Prev").Cells(ii, 22)).Value = _
     Worksheets("UPT Report").Range(Worksheets("UPT Report").Cells(i, 1), Worksheets("UPT Report").Cells(i, 22)).Value
     Else
      Worksheets("UPT Prev").Range(Worksheets("UPT Prev").Cells(lastblankrow, 1), Worksheets("UPT Prev").Cells(lastblankrow, 22)).Value = _
      Worksheets("UPT Report").Range(Worksheets("UPT Report").Cells(i, 1), Worksheets("UPT Report").Cells(i, 22)).Value
      lastblankrow = lastblankrow + 1
  End If
```

Next ii
Next i

its now moving the data over, but doubling up the lines.

so 2 rows are added for each row that should be 1

heres whats being added currently, first 2 rows are in place before macro run

```
1   Test    Test Mgr    -12 Test 1
2   Test    Test Mgr    -13 Test 1
1   Test    Test Mgr    -12 Test 1
2   Test    Test Mgr    -13 Test 1
3   Test    Test Mgr    -12 #N/A
3   Test    Test Mgr    -12 #N/A
4   Test    Test Mgr    -12 #N/A
4   Test    Test Mgr    -12 #N/A
5   Test    Test Mgr    -12 #N/A
5   Test    Test Mgr    -12 #N/A
6   Test    Test Mgr    -12 #N/A
6   Test    Test Mgr    -12 #N/A
7   Test    Test Mgr    -12 #N/A
7   Test    Test Mgr    -12 #N/A
8   Test    Test Mgr    -12 #N/A
8   Test    Test Mgr    -12 #N/A
9   Test    Test Mgr    -12 #N/A
9   Test    Test Mgr    -12 #N/A
10  Test    Test Mgr    -12 #N/A
10  Test    Test Mgr    -12 #N/A
12  Phil    Zkim    12  #N/A
12  Phil    Zkim    12  #N/A
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on? I'm going to bet it's inside the first loop...You *should always* qualify all ranges with the worksheet. You do so with `Range()`, but also should do it with `Cells()`, i.e. `Worksheets("UPT Prev").Range(Worksheets("UPT Prev").Cells(ii, 1), Worksheets("UPT Prev").Cells(ii, 22)).Value`, etc.

Comment: still get the subscript out of range in the first iteration.

Comment: does the answer I posted still throw the error?

Comment: yes sir, both ranges of data are copy paste duplicates, best i can figure is formatting error along the way.

Comment: how did you declare your lastrows?

Comment: Worksheets("UPT Report").Activate
      lastRowReport = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row                                                
      lastRowPrev = Worksheets("UPT Prev").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: with that code run before the loops

Comment: You need to make sure to put the worksheet before `Rows.Count`, otherwise it's going to count the rows with the ActiveSheet, FYI.

Comment: it loops through without error but now on the 2nd iteratons forward it makes 10 + copies of each row after the initial data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does this work?

```
Sub t()
  For i = 3 To lastRowReport
   For ii = 3 To lastRowPrev
      If Worksheets("UPT Report").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("UPT Prev").Cells(ii, 1) Then
         Worksheets("UPT Prev").Range(Worksheets("UPT Prev").Cells(ii, 1), Worksheets("UPT Prev").Cells(ii, 22)).Value = _
         Worksheets("UPT Report").Range(Worksheets("UPT Report").Cells(i, 1), Worksheets("UPT Report").Cells(i, 22)).Value
       Else
        Worksheets("UPT Report").Range(Worksheets("UPT Report").Cells(i, 1), Worksheets("UPT Report").Cells(i, 22)).Copy
        Worksheets("UPT Prev").Cells(Worksheets("UPT Prev").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      End If
   Next ii
Next i
End Sub
```

Basically, I just qualified all the `Cells()` and `Rows.Count` with the worksheet (I assume) it should be called from.  Also you had a typo in `PastSpecial`.

Also, when splitting a command over two lines, you need to "connect" then with `_` like I did in the first `If` statement.

This can be tidied up a little though if you want to use `With Worksheets("UPT Report")` and setting two ranges' values equal (instead of copy/paste special Values) for example, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: was a minor typo in the naming, but instead of coping row to row, this gives me 10 rows of each matching

Comment: @Humbrol2 - Step through the macro with `F8`. Is the part you mention that first `If` statement? Where it copies columns 1-22?  What do you mean it gives you 10 rows matching? Perhaps it'll help to show what your data looks like, and what you want as the output (edited into OP)?

Comment: thinking i need to break the loop if a match is found and move on to the next i and each time it runs, it still wants to add to each row at the end,, something with the if then might be broken :/